# Owl-carousel height being set to largest item first

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I've just started a new job and one of my first tasks is to fix an issue with the carousel on one of their clients websites.
Long story short when you load the page there is a large area of white space below the first video in the carousel.
After doing a few console logs it seems like the carousel height is defaulting to the largest item in the DOM even though it's not the active item. If you resize the screen it corrects itself but as soon as you refresh the whitespace returns.

Below is where all of the options are and the custom height calculator function.
I've been working on this all day but haven't really gotten anywhere with it.

I'm not sure if that code snippet will be of much help but if anyone has encountered something similar and could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

```js
  // Homepage Banner Carousel
  if ($('#home-banner-carousel').length > 0) {

    $('#home-banner-carousel').imagesLoaded(function () {

      var owl = $('#home-banner-carousel');
      owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(e) {
          var current = e.item.index;
          var video = $(e.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("video");
        //   var videoHeight = $('.owl-item.active').height();
          if (video.length) {
            // console.log(videoHeight);
            $(e.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("video").get(0).play();
            //$('owl-stage-outer').css('height', videoHeight);
          }
      }).owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        margin: 0,
        dots: true,
        nav: true,
        animateOut: "fadeOut",
        navText: ["", ""],
        navContainer: ".carousel-controls",
        video: true,
        autoplay:false,
        autoplayTimeout:10000,
        loop: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
        touchDrag: false,
        autoHeight:true,
        callbacks: true,
        onInitialized: setOwlStageHeight,
        onResized: setOwlStageHeight,
        onTranslated: setOwlStageHeight,
        onTranslate: function(property) {
          var current = property.item.index;
          var video = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("video");
        //   console.log(video.height());
          if (video.length) {
            $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("video").get(0).play();
          } else {
          $('.owl-item').find('video').each(function() {
              this.pause();
          });
          }
        }
      });
function setOwlStageHeight(event) {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.owl-item.active').each(function () { // LOOP THROUGH ACTIVE ITEMS
        var thisHeight = parseInt( $(this).height() );
        console.log(thisHeight);
        maxHeight=(maxHeight>=thisHeight?maxHeight:thisHeight);
        console.log(maxHeight);
    });
    $('.owl-carousel').css('height', maxHeight );
    $('.owl-stage-outer').css('height', maxHeight ); // CORRECT DRAG-AREA SO BUTTONS ARE CLICKABLE
}
    });

  }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need change " autoHeight: true " to " autoHeight: false "

Comment: Thanks for your advice, although unfortunately that has no effect :(